# AS3 - Private Object. Make property as read only

Tags: class, actionscript-3, properties, readonly

I have a object property in my `Class` which is private and marked as read-only.

```
private var readOnlyObj:Object;
```

I can only access it with a get method:

```
public function get readOnly(){ return readOnlyObj }
```

I can access it by:

```
var objClass = new MyClass();
trace(objClass.readOnly)
```

And if i'll try to modify it:

```
objClass.readOnly = new Object();
```

I'll get an error:

> Error# Property is read only.

Now my question is:

How do I set the properties of my `readOnlyObj` as `read-only`?

If I have set the object in the constructor:

```
readOnlyObj["property1"] = 0;
```

And modify that property by:

```
objClass.readOnly["property1"] = 2;
```

It is valid. I want set the `property1` to a `read-only` property. Is this possible? Thank You!

Comment: You do misunderstand scope here. readOnly is a property of MyClass instances but in readOnly["property1"] , property1 is not a property of MyClass, it is a property of readOnly. So in no way an instance of MyClass can modify the access of any property of readOnly.

Comment: Yes i know that. I'm asking if its possible to make properties of `objects` to `read-only`. if you have a solution im glad to hear it :)

Comment: If you are asking if properties of Object instance can be read only the answer is no. If you are asking if property of an instance property can be made read only from the instance scope the answer is no as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do this, at least in the way you describe. You can of course make your `readOnly` object a custom class instance that only has read-only properties, but you can't freeze a dynamic `Object` instance.

Comment: Oh i see. Thank You for your response @Aaron :) i made like that because i want to store objects that are read only, in my actually code, the object holds `ids` generated by the class. i dont want users to modify the ids. just read/acess it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by returning a duplicate of the original object and not the object itself.

The `transform` properties of `DisplayObjects` work like this: you can get the object property from a `get function` and can modify the object, but such modification has no effect until you pass the modified object back to the `set function`.

In your case, there's no way to give the object back (no setter) and by returning a copy (commonly called 'clone') from the getter, there is no way to modify the object property from outside, because the returned reference reference the newly created independent clone, essentially making the internal object constant.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is not possible and only yield the answer "no" if on the other hand you asked about how to achieve that functionality then there would be a few answer possible.

First of all given your code and the problem at hand it is clear that you misunderstand the class scope. You set:

```
private var readOnlyObj:Object;
```

As read only while it's really not the object you want to protect, it's its properties. So readOnlyObj should really not even be visible and accessible.

Now that readOnlyObj is private and not accessible, you can put together a simple method to retrieve properties:

```
public function getProperty(name:String):*
{
    if(readOnlyObj[name] != undefined)
    {
        return readOnlyObj[name];
    }
    return null;
}
```

It might also be useful to know how to put together a public setter that cannot be used externally. 
Create an internal Boolean variable (only with true package), then internally set that variable to true before setting the property then set it back to false. Since externally that boolean cannot be set you end up with a public setter that cannot be used externally.

```
internal var allowSetter:Boolean;

public function set whatever(value:*):void
{
    if(allowSetter)
    {
        //set property ect...
        allowSetter = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can actually see and read the properties of read only by the `get method` above. `instanceObject.readOnly` without the `()` will return me the private `readOnlyObj` but in read-only

Comment: That's not correct, once again you do not understand scope. As a private variable it can only be accessed within the instance scope.

Comment: I think you haven't read the  "read only by get method" part. I know that private is instance only. `public function get readOnly(){ return readOnlyObj; }`

Comment: In my answer I specifically say that this needs to be removed so readOnlyObj stays private. You do not need readOnlyObj to be accessible at all.